# Cannot resolve Request Header Issue in ModSecurity and its affects on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, owasp, request-headers, mod-security

CURRENT: I have the familiar issue with an internal 403 coming up... however, after exploring for the issue through all error logs, I have found that the Forbidden error is emerging from a Modsecurity issue regarding `Request Headers` and flagging up rulesets within, modsecurity_crs_21_protocal / OWASP_CRS.

ORIGINAL: I could not access my site at all.  While I can now log in to my domain.co.uk, and navigate around - after modifying the `wp-config.php` from many suggestions, replacing and modifying again my `.htaccess`, as well as resolving a missing:

- `[http/2.0]` within, modsecurity_crs_10_config,

PROGRESS: The internal WordPress issue persists and shows itself when trying to configure/change the dynamics of the site, particularly, time and date settings, permalinks, editing pages by any means, and generally when I try to save any changes.

NOTES: VPS, CentOS, not - cPanel. Fresh install of WordPress, as my own is held on a shared drive.

- All directories are set to [755] and files to [644].
- I have also normalised the SQL database to be `UTF8mb4_unicode.ci`  -- in the event this could help, it has sped things up but nothing else.

EXPLORING: When exploring modsecurity.d I have browsed far and wide and found a few mods for modsecurity_crs_10_config that was proposed to work, by excluding

- error log `[id='******']`,

along with coding in

- `[SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "/wp-admin/load-scripts.php]`

but nothing seems to be resolving the issue!!

====

`# (CRS new ruleset)

**Rule to allow server-status requests with missing mandatory headers.**

`SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch ***.***.*.**"` 
`"msg:'Matched 1***.***.*.** and matched server-status. Disabling rules *****1 and *****2',`
`phase:1,`
`id:1*****,`
`t:none,`
`pass,`
`log,`
`chain"`
`SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "server-status$"` 
`"t:none,`
`ctl:ruleRemoveById=*****1,`
`ctl:ruleRemoveById=*****2"`

**Rule to allow load-scripts.php requests without triggering rules.**

`SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "/wp-admin/load-scripts.php$"` 
`"msg:'Disabled rules *****1 and *****2 for load-scripts.php$',`
`phase:1,`
`nolog,`
`pass,`
`ctl:ruleRemoveById=*****1,`
`ctl:ruleRemoveById=*****2,`
`` id:'2*****'"` ``

====

While remembering that there seem to be variations between server directory/file paths:
Do the above look ok, or do I need to be doing something else?
Am I in the right place (file) to be applying these rules?

Thanks in advance and I will try to answer any questions you have in as much detail as you need.

KR, John

**Have tried**:
I have tried updating file permissions 755 & 644, config.php,.htaccess, normalised sql database, modsec engine is on, apache status - no issues, and modified rulesets to modsecurity_crs_10_config.

**Expecting**:
Check if I have got the right coding/syntax in the right place/order and more importantly in the right file, or if I need to be doing something different.

**===================== [[ UPDATE ]] =====================**

This may seem a little long-winded, however... less id specific details, as per request, here are the results of updating:

CentOS:      7.9
Iworx:       7
Apache:      2.4.52
ModSecurity: 2.2.9
OWSAP:       3.3.2
PHP:         7.4
APR, PCRE, LIBXML:  Installed

Error Logs (All commented out IP addresses don't belong to me either!).

==================== [[ START ERROR LOGS ]] ====================

**Audit.log**: Last three entries

--d0a9ea60-C--

```
action=health-check-site-status-result&_wpnonce=015c390f17&counts%5Bgood%5D=18&counts%5Brecommended%5D=1&counts%5Bcritical%5D=0
```

--d0a9ea60-F--

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Length: 199
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Mon, 28 Mar 2022 17:03:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.52 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_watch/4.3 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6
```

--d0a9ea60-H--

```
Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"] [line "159"] 
[id "981173"] [rev "2"] [msg "Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded"] 
[data "Matched Data: - found within ARGS:action: health-check-site-status-result"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"]
Action: Intercepted (phase 2)
Apache-Handler: proxy:fcgi://names123-remi-php74-proxy
Stopwatch: 1648487015800212 8861 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1648487015800212 8861; combined=6733, p1=899, p2=5347, p3=0, p4=0, p5=348, sr=139, sw=139, l=0, gc=0
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.3 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/2.2.9; OWASP_CRS/3.3.2.
Server: Apache/2.4.52 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"
```

Modsecurity.d/activated_rules/ CRS_41 (159):

```
SecRule ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "([\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\+\=\{\}\[\]\|\:\;\"\'\´\’\‘\`\<\>].*?){4,}" "phase:2,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,block,id:'981173',rev:'2',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',maturity:'9',accuracy:'8',msg:'Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded',capture,logdata:'Matched Data: %{TX.1} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR}',tag:'OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.warning_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.sql_injection_score=+1,setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/RESTRICTED_SQLI_CHARS-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0}"
```

**NOTES**: `d0a9ea60-H` appears to be a result of `d0a9ea60-C` which may explain why WordPress will intially complete a health check and comes back healthy - but will not conduct any other tests (Theme and Plugin, etc)?

**Web Server Error Log**: Last two entries

```
[Mon Mar 28 18:55:13 2022] [-:error] [pid 27563:tid 140237342709504] [client **.***.***.*:40074] [client **.***.***.*] ModSecurity: Warning. Operator GE matched 0 at 
TX:outbound_anomaly_score. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION.conf"] [line "102"] [id "980140"] 
[msg "Outbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (score 0): individual paranoia level scores: , , , "] 
[ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "Host: domain.na.me"] [tag "event-correlation"] [hostname "domain.na.me"] [uri "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php"] 
[unique_id "YkIEkcSvwnZVNnEcbqtwCgAAAHA"]

[Mon Mar 28 18:55:13 2022] [-:error] [pid 27563:tid 140237342709504] [client **.***.***.*:40074] [client **.***.***.*] ModSecurity: Warning. Operator GE matched 0 at 
TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION.conf"] [line "91"] [id "980130"] 
[msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Inbound Score: 0 - SQLI=0,XSS=0,RFI=,LFI=,RCE=,PHPI=,HTTP=,SESS=): individual paranoia level scores: , , , "] 
[ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "Host: domain.na.me"] [tag "event-correlation"] [hostname "domain.na.me"] [uri "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php"]
[unique_id "YkIEkcSvwnZVNnEcbqtwCgAAAHA"]
```

modsecurity-crs/rules/ RESPONSE_980_CORRELATION (91, 102):

```
82.  SecRule TX:INBOUND_ANOMALY_SCORE "@ge %{tx.inbound_anomaly_score_threshold}" \
83.     "id:980130,\
84.     phase:5,\
85.     pass,\
86.     t:none,\
87.     log,\
88.     noauditlog,\
89.     msg:'Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Inbound Score: %{TX.INBOUND_ANOMALY_SCORE} - SQLI=%{tx.sql_injection_score},XSS=%{tx.xss_score},RFI=%{tx.rfi_score},LFI=%{tx.lfi_score},RCE=%{tx.rce_score},PHPI=%{tx.php_injection_score},HTTP=%{tx.http_violation_score},SESS=%{tx.session_fixation_score}): individual paranoia level scores: %{TX.ANOMALY_SCORE_PL1}, %{TX.ANOMALY_SCORE_PL2}, %{TX.ANOMALY_SCORE_PL3}, %{TX.ANOMALY_SCORE_PL4}',\
90.     tag:'event-correlation',\
91.>>   ver:'OWASP_CRS/3.3.2'"

93.  SecRule TX:OUTBOUND_ANOMALY_SCORE "@ge %{tx.outbound_anomaly_score_threshold}" \
94.     "id:980140,\
95.     phase:5,\
96.     pass,\
97.     t:none,\
98.     log,\
99.     noauditlog,\
100.    msg:'Outbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (score %{TX.OUTBOUND_ANOMALY_SCORE}): individual paranoia level scores: %{TX.OUTBOUND_ANOMALY_SCORE_PL1}, %{TX.OUTBOUND_ANOMALY_SCORE_PL2}, %{TX.OUTBOUND_ANOMALY_SCORE_PL3}, %{TX.OUTBOUND_ANOMALY_SCORE_PL4}',\
101.    tag:'event-correlation',\
102.>>  ver:'OWASP_CRS/3.3.2'"
```

**NOTES**:  There could well be a version issue, or conflict, while I cannot see earlier installed versions of OWASP, it is becoming possible that the files are embedded elsewhere, or not named properly, in the system and are causing a conflict?

**/etc/httpd/logs/error_log**: Main block entry

```
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:02 2022] [suexec:notice] [pid 27330:tid 140238080026752] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:02 2022] [-:notice] [pid 27330:tid 140238080026752] ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.3 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:02.447352 2022] [:notice] [pid 27330:tid 140238080026752] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.5.2"; loaded version="1.5.2"
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:02.447358 2022] [:notice] [pid 27330:tid 140238080026752] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.32 "; loaded version="8.32 2012-11-30"
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:02.447363 2022] [:notice] [pid 27330:tid 140238080026752] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.1"
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:02.447413 2022] [:notice] [pid 27330:tid 140238080026752] ModSecurity: StatusEngine call: "2.9.3,Apache/2.4.52 (CentOS) Op,1.5.2/1.5.2,8.32/8.32 2012-11-30,(null),2.9.1,d052a9a3f6f1e10728f8450a585dba54e25cb3b4"
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:04.510608 2022] [:notice] [pid 27330:tid 140238080026752] ModSecurity: StatusEngine call failed. Query: GIXDSLRTFRAXAYLDNBSS6MROGQXDKMRA.FBBWK3TUJ5JSSICPOAWDCLRVFYZC6MJO.GUXDELBYFYZTELZYFYZTEIBSGAYTELJR.GEWTGMBMFBXHK3DMFEWDELRZFYYSYZBQ.GUZGCOLBGNTDMZRRMUYTANZSHBTDQNBV.GBQTKOBVMRRGCNJUMUZDKY3CGNRDI.1648489142.status.modsecurity.org
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:04.552056 2022] [so:warn] [pid 27330:tid 140238080026752] AH01574: module security2_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:04.552090 2022] [so:warn] [pid 27330:tid 140238080026752] AH01574: module unique_id_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:04 2022] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 27330:tid 140238080026752] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:04 2022] [-:notice] [pid 27368:tid 140238080026752] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 27368)
[Mon Mar 28 17:39:04 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 27330:tid 140238080026752] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_watch/4.3 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

==================== [[ END ERROR LOGS ]] ====================

**A**) Ensured everything was clear and updated
**B**) As you can see, I have installed the necessary modules/software, as both ModSecurity - and the new Modsecurity-CRS is being called on.  `[Mon Mar 28 17:39:04.510608 2022] StatusEngine failed`, was due to a syntax error, which I corrected.
**C**) I have taken out the earlier coding from `modsecurity.d/modsecurity_crs_10`, and placed it in `modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION` as per the install instructions. The code has been modified slightly to accept a range as opposed to a list.

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /wp-admin/" \
  "msg:'Matched REQUEST URI and matched server-status. Disabling rules 960008 - 960017',\
  phase:1,\
  id:1881,\
  t:none,\
  pass,\
  log,\
  chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_URI "server-status$" \
      "t:none,\
        ctl:ruleRemoveById=960008-960017"
```

**D**) Uncommented lines 350-361 (`crs_exclusions_wordpress=1`) within `modsecurity-crs/crs-setup`
**E**) Have also, as per instructions, implemented the following into, `httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule security2_module>
   Include modsecurity-crs/crs-setup.conf
   Include modsecurity-crs/rules/*.conf
</IfModule>

LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
```

-- [[ RUN ]] --

`$ sudo systemctl restart httpd.service -- successfull`
`$ sudo systemctl status -l httpd.service -- Active (running)`

Unfortunately, I still have the same issues.

There is a distinct chance I may not have linked something somewhere or may have not uncommented something, it could well be that I have uncommented too many with a high setting!

Hope this helps?

Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

CRS Dev-On-Duty here. It seems like you are facing an [OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set](https://coreruleset.org/) false positive that could possibly be covered by the Wordpress rule exclusion package.
To activate this rule exclusion package, enable the rule 900130 in the [crs-setup.conf](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.4/dev/crs-setup.conf.example#L351) and enable the appropriate package.

To get more information about the [Core Rule Set installation](https://www.netnea.com/cms/apache-tutorials/apache-tutorial-7_including-modsecurity-core-rules) and to understand [Core Rule Set tuning](https://www.netnea.com/cms/apache-tutorials/apache-tutorial-8_handling-false-positives-modsecurity-core-rule-set/) process in general, please have a look at these linked, excellent Core Rule Set tutorials.

If the problem persists, then I need more information to help you:

Please provide the following if possible:

- Full alert message (ideally send us the full audit log of the request)
- Web server and version or the platform you are using
- ModSecurity version
- CRS version

ATTENTION: When submitting logs, please remove all personal information like IP addresses, hostnames, passwords, etc.

We'll be happy to have a look afterwards.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry it took so long to respond. I didn't notice that you updated your issue. I've only seen it now  as I'm OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set (CRS) dev-on-duty again.

First of all I think you now have a conflict with two different CRS versions.
When I see `modsecurity_crs_21_protocal` and `modsecurity_crs_10_config` I see that you have loaded OWASP CRS version 2.
Here is what the CRS version 2 rules look like: https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/tree/v2.2/master/base_rules

Current version is OWASP CRS 3: https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/tree/v3.3/master/rules
As you see the rule files have different names and numbering.
I see these CRS 3 rules in your "Web Server Error Log" and when I see `modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE_980_CORRELATION`.

I also suspect this conflict when I see the following log line / log section `H`:
`Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.3 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/2.2.9; OWASP_CRS/3.3.2.`

So I think the first step is to remove the old CRS version 2.

I see that you are loading the OWASP ModSecurity CRS rules here:

```
<IfModule security2_module>
   Include modsecurity-crs/crs-setup.conf
   Include modsecurity-crs/rules/*.conf
</IfModule>
```

Are there only CRS 3 rules in this directory modsecurity-crs/rules/? I think so.

So questions are: how do you install the OWASP CRS rules? And where are the CRS version 2 rules loaded and can you remove the loading of these rules?

Then, we'll take the next step and have a look at the log files again when the old rules are gone.

This time I'll follow the changes on this issue!

Comment: How do, and thanks for replying, @franbuehler.

Ah!

Now, this is not something I recognise on my system anywhere...  I'll have a look at bringing that lot across and installing it.  I'll let you know what happens before moving ahead any further.

Appreciated.

Comment: I recognize the CRS when I see the following: "Request Headers and flagging up rulesets within, modsecurity_crs_21_protocal / OWASP_CRS"
It would be helpful to see the actual rule that blocked the request.
But, yes read the links I posted, add the exclusion package and let me know what happens...

Comment: Hi, @franbuehler

I have updated the main topic with everything you have asked for...  I have also commented out any sensitive data.  Hope this helps and apprecieted.

Comment: a bit more progress...  a few more tweaks later and I have moved from an `internal 403 forbidden error` - to being booted out with a `status 302 (phase 2). redirect to http://homepage.co.uk`.  So I'm getting there!